# WMI in VBScript Fails

Tags: vbscript, activex, wmi, ip-address

We are currently having an issue with our installer for one customer.  The installer runs a bit of VBScript to retrieve their current IP Address.  For some reason on this customers machine it returns the following error:

Script Error -2146827859. Microsoft VBScript Runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'objWMIService.ExecQuery'

Here is the VBScript we are running:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\localhost\root\cimv2")
Set colAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled = True")

For each objAdapter in colAdapters
    If Not IsNull(objAdapter.IPAddress) Then
        For i = LBound(objAdapter.IPAddress) To UBound(objAdapter.IPAddress)
            if objAdapter.IPAddress(i)<>"0.0.0.0" then 
                if instr(objAdapter.IPAddress(i),":") > 0 Then
                    'This is an IPv6 Address.
                Else
                    session.property("IPADDRESS") = objAdapter.IPAddress(i) 
                end if
            end if
        Next
     end if
next
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Windows is your customer running?

Comment: It could be that all the WMI classes aren't registered or you're running it under an account that doesn't have elevated access (ie. running as an admin)

Comment: Try [rebuilding the WMI repo](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2009/04/13/wmi-rebuilding-the-wmi-repository.aspx).

Comment: @QuickNull Enumerating the adapters should work even for non-admin users.